# Cómo obtener una variable de un script para utilizarla en un select / option de un formulario modal Google Apps Script

Tags: html, formularios, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

necesito vuestra ayuda. No he encontrado nada para resolver mi problema. Tengo un script donde elimina los valores duplicados de una lista de valores almacenada en una hoja de google sheet llamada "Country" (Por ejemplo valores con paises duplicados: Francia, España, Bélgica, Francia, Portugal, España). No consigo introducir la variable del script opSindupli que lo que hace es eliminar los duplicados de esa hoja en un select option de un formulario modal que se llama desde un index.html

---

Código añadido en code.gs, entre otros

````
    function getOptions(){
        var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/
        1YD1II2ELIJNMktAgPqrrx1nUngoxd4wz2r09Dg11hrE/edit#gid=0");
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Country");
        var data = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(d => d[0] !=="");
        var newArr =data.map(d => d[0]);
        var uniqueList = [];
         newArr.map(r => {
         if(uniqueList.indexOf(r) === -1){
         uniqueList.push(r);
         }
         })
        return uniqueList.sort();
        
        
        };
        
        var opSindupli= getOptions().map(d => "<option>" + d + "</option>").join("");
    
    Código index.html que llama a form5.html modal
    
    ```<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
        <head>
    
      <base target="_top">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    /head>
    
    <body onload="createStateDropdown()">
      <div class="container">
    
        <!-- The Modal Form -->
        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
    
              <!-- Modal Header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>Formulario</h2>
                <button type="button" id="btn-close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="clearForm();">x</button>
              </div>
    
                  <!-- Modal body -->
                   <!-- See Form5.html file -->
                   <?!= include('form5'); ?>
    
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
    
    Código form5.html
    
         <form id="myForm" class="p-2 border border-light rounded bg-light" 
          onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">   
            <div id="message"></div>
            <input type="text" id="RecId" name="RecId" value="" style="display: none">
            <div class="form-row">
             <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="name" >Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
          </div>
             <div class="form-row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">State</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="State" name="State" required>
              <option selected disabled value="">select</option>
            </select>
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Gala</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="gala" name="gala" required>
                     
                      <option selected disabled value="">select</option>
                   </select>
    
                   
                </div>
    
                
    
    
            <div class="form-group col-md-6" >
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control date" id="date" name="date"  required>
          </div>
          </div> 
            <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="data1" >Mobile No</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data1" name="data1" 
          placeholder="Mobile No" 
          required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="data2" >Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data2" name="data2" 
          placeholder="Address" 
          required>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="data3" >Remarks</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data3" name="data3" 
          placeholder="Remarks"` 
          required>
          </div>
        </div>
          <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn bd-blue-500" >Submit</button>
        <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>

intento añadir la variable de code.gs llamada opSindupli mediante ?!= opSindupli; ?>, pero no funciona en el formulario modal
 
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">State</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="State" name="State" required>
      <option selected disabled value="">Select</option>
     ?!= opSindupli; ?>
    </select>
     </div>

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?
Si necesitáis algún dato más, me decís. Mil gracias por la ayuda.
````

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que podrías usar el servicio `HtmlService` de AppsScript para generar el contenido de tu control en el formulario, [Esta es la parte relevante](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates?hl=es#calling_apps_script_apis_directly) de la documentación, ya que generar tu contenido desde guiones de `HtmlService` te permite llamar directamente a las API de Workspace al momento de generar tu contenido:

```js
// Code.gs

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <? var data = SpreadsheetApp
        .openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        .getActiveSheet()
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues(); ?>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

El ejemplo está generando una tabla, sin embargo bien podrian ser los items de tu selector de países.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. No me sirve (o puede que no sepa confugurarlo), porque mi formulario no se abre con HtmlService de function doGet(), sino desde <?!= include('form5'); ?> del código siguiente alojado en code.gs:                                                        function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
.getContent();  }

Comment: Hola, ¿alguien que pueda ayudarme?